# Magento 2 : Configurable Product Quick Add to Cart Not Working

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart

I am on category page and want to quick add product to cart. It works fine for simple products but not for configurables.

I select color and size and click `Add to Card` and it redirected to product detail page with following notification:

> You need to choose options for your item.
>      The selected Item is in stock

Comment: have you find a solution for it?